# Random Generator automatically Random

Tags: java, android, random

As we know the following code is to Random Number

```
Random generator = new Random();
number = generator.nextInt(VALUE) + 1;
```

and i make this code to Random generator if the button click

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonblack);
if(v==button1) {

 // Here, we are generating a random number
 Random generator = new Random();
 number = generator.nextInt(5) + 1; 
 // The '5' is the number of values

 // Here, we are checking to see what the output of the random was
 switch(number) { 

     case 1: if(bla.. bla.. bla.. == 1){
             //Do some blaa. blaa. blaa. logic
         }
        else if(bla.. bla.. bla.. == 2){
             //Do some blaa. blaa. blaa. logic
         }
         break;
       //and so on..
```

My question is how to make Random Generator method is automatically Random every 2 second then increasingly faster, not by clicking a button

and how to make random stop if some button clicked, example

```
buttonstop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);    
buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){ 

            //Stop Random generator  

        }
     });
```

Anyone can Answer? Thank's

Comment: make an loop or do it on a thread there are so many ways to achieve this

Comment: ... use a Timer? an infinite loop (with an exit point on some condition)?

Comment: Basically, your question is not about random number generation at all. You could cut that out completely from this question. Your question is how to repreatedly do something on the user interface in a timed way. Google for it.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yup some like that, just like piano tiles but this more different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use it which starts from 2 seconds to faster by 20 milliseconds

```
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    int ms=2000; //2secs.
    Define a Runnable:

    private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // get random number here

        // You could do this call if you wanted it to be periodic:

    ms=ms-20; //20ms faster
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, ms);

            }
        };

    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
```

Comment: Don't forget to call mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask) in onPause or onStop activity's methods

Comment: as @llya says also stop handler if you want, because that's a common sense

Comment: @ chairizky, my pleasure